# ChemSpider property query

Tags: python

Is there a way to access properties (e.g. predicted properties from EPISuite) through the chemspipy wrapper? I have found how to access the ChemSpider database through chemspipy, and I can query to access properties such as molecular_weight [http://chemspipy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/compound.html#compound-properties], but I want to get to the detailed properties such as melting point and boiling point. The properties are available through EPISuite on the ChemSpider website.

Answer (score 1):

take a look on kinda RESTful API: http://parts.chemspider.com/json.ashx

For example to get all information related to some compound (aspirin in this case) you can use this endpoint http://parts.chemspider.com/JSON.ashx?op=GetRecordsAsCompounds&csids[0]=2157

Comment: Thanks -- is there a tutorial on how to use this API? I'm finding it pretty opaque.

Comment: @user3450049, what exactly you are finding as opaque? For me it looks pretty straightforward, however it's to really canonical RESTful API. What task are you trying to solve?